# Malformed url passed to a angularjs factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service who called a url (and i have more than only one URL, i just want to pass any url from a controller to factory)

```
var youtubeURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet';

ConnectivityService.check({myurl: youtubeURL}, function(responseSCon) {
```

and in the factory :

```
return $resource(
    ':myurl',
    null,
    {
        'check': {method: 'GET', params: {myurl: '@myurl'}, isArray: false, cache: false, headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}}
    }
);
```

problem is that the url called is  `https://%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fyoutube%2Fv3%2Fvideos%3Fpart%3Dsnippet/`

I tried $sce, encode/decode URI, nothing works... How to correctly pass a url ?

Answer (score 0):

it appears the url has been encoded. To decode it, you can use the javascript native decodeURIComponent.

For example:

```
decodeURIComponent("https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fyoutube%2Fv3%2Fvideos%3Fpart%3Dsnippet")
```

it will give you the correct url.

is that what you wanted?

Comment: always error : Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fyoutube%2Fv3%2Fvideos%3Fpart%3Dsnippet/'.